# Differential equation in terms of the dependent variable

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

This is *not* a home work question.
What is the way to solve the following differential equation (other than numerical methods please):

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{-k}{y^2}$$

where $k > 0$ and $k$ is a constant.

I am looking for a solution that expresses the dependent variable, y in terms of the independent variable, x.

Comment: multiply by $y'$ and integrate.

Comment: Using abel's hint, you will be able to express $x$ as a nasty function of $y$.

Comment: If the context is physical, can you give your preferred initial conditions ?

Comment: @Tony Piccolo: The context is physical actually. However, the question belongs here as I would like a solution that is based purely on calculus without relying on any physics.

If initial conditions are useful, they are: at x = 0, y = R where R > 0 and and R is a constant. I am not adding the initial conditions to the question as I think that may not help solve the equations that much.

Comment: My aim was to avoid considering several cases. By the way, you need _two_ conditions: usually one considers $y'(0)=0$ .

Comment: @Tony Piccolo: Sorry. The initial conditions are: 
at $x = 0$,
$y = R$ and $y' = V_0$
where $R > 0$ and $V_0 > 0$, $R$ and $V_0$ are constants.

Answer (score 2):

As abel commented, starting with $$y'' = -\frac{k}{y^2}$$ multiply both sides by $2y'$ to get $$2y'y''=-2k\frac{y'}{y^2}$$ and integrating once with respect to $y$ gives $$(y')^2=\frac{2k}{y}+c_1$$ that is to say $$y'=\pm \sqrt{\frac{2k}{y}+c_1}$$ which is separable $$x'=\pm \frac 1 {\sqrt{\frac{2k}{y}+c_1}}$$ which is a very unpleasant integral to handle.

I must confess that I gave up but using a CAS, the result obtained seems to be $$x=\pm \Big(\frac{\sqrt{y} \sqrt{c_1 y+2 k}}{c_1}-\frac{2 k \log \left(\sqrt{c_1} \sqrt{c_1 y+2 k}+c_1
   \sqrt{y}\right)}{c_1^{3/2}}+c_2 \Big)$$ which is not the most funny expression I ever met.

Comment: I am not sure if the integration with respect to y is correct as y' and y'' represent differentials with respect to x. Also, the final equation expresses x, the independent variable in terms of y, dependent variable. However, what would normally be useful is an equation that expresses the dependent variable in terms of the independent variable. I have updated my question to clarify that.

Comment: @QuandoSumus With reference to the last sentence of your comment, that is not always possible if you want a symbolic result. Your equation is a well known example.